# PriorityQueue and ternary operator

Tags: java, priority-queue, ternary-operator

In  method_one:

1. `PriorityQueue<Integer> bigger = lower.size() > higher.size() ? lower : higher;`
2. `PriorityQueue<Integer> smaller = lower.size() > higher.size() ? higher : lower;`

In method_two:

3. `PriorityQueue<Integer> bigger = lower.size() > higher.size() ? lower : higher;`
4. `PriorityQueue<Integer> smaller = lower.size() < higher.size() ? lower : higher;`

Here `lower` is Max_heap priority queue, and `higher` is Min_heap priority queue.

Line 2 and 4 are same, but getting wrong answers.
And getting right answer when using line 2 at line 4.
Why this strange behaviour, even they are same?

Comment: `lower.size()` is lower than `higher.size()` right?

Comment: What do you mean by WRONG ANSWERS?

Comment: I am using this result for further calculation, and getting different result,

Comment: lower and higher are max and min heap, they can be of any size @RoshanaPitigala

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Outputs  `1 = 3` and `2 = 4`. What do you want to do?

Comment: *"Line 2 and 4 are same"* They are **not** the same. The inverse of `>` is `<=`, not `<`. The two statements produce different results if sizes are equal. There is no "strange behaviour". The code does exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: @Andreas thanks :) It worked. post this in answer so that others can also see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in line **2**:

`if lower.size() == higher.size()` then choose **lower**

in line **4**:

`if lower.size() == higher.size()` then chose **higher**

thats the difference. You get different answer if you something do wrong when work with higher priority queue or lower priority queue.

From [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) comment in question this line added:

The inverse of `>` is `<=`, not `<`

Comment: Yes! But why this strange behaviour.

Comment: to detect why strange behaveiour then need to know what are you doing with priority queue

Comment: give neccesseray code in question

Comment: Code is too long, I am solving running median problem, and using this, for getting which priority Queue is of larger size, and balancing the priority queue, according to it .

Comment: i think there is problem . because for case 2 you work with lower priority queue and for case 4 you work with higher priority que

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176743/discussion-between-abhishec-kumar-and-sajib).

Comment: without code. not possible to detect your problem